# What doees "this" keyword refer in this code block in c++?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, this

```
const newString& newString::operator=(const newString& rightStr)
{
    if(this!=&rightStr)
    {
        delete[] strPtr;
        strLength=rightStr.strLength;
        strPtr = newChar[strLength+1];
        strcpy(strPtr,rightStr.strPtr);
    }
    return* this;
}
```

I know it avoids self copy, but what does "this" keyword refer to? I mean I thought it was rightStr but then why would it chechk if its equal to itself?

Answer (score 4):

In a non-static class method, the [`this` keyword](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/this) is defined by the C++ language as a pointer to the object that the current class method was invoked on.

In your case, `this` refers to the `newString` object on the *left* side of the assignment statement that invoked `newString::operator=`. For example, in the below code:

```cpp
newString strSrc, strDest;
strDest = strSrc;
```

Inside of `newString::operator=`, `this` is a pointer to the `strDest` object, and `rightStr` is a reference to the `strSrc` object.

Answer (score 0):

"This" keyword can be used to pass current object as a parameter to another method or it can be used to refer current class instance variable.